# Is this problem solvable as stated, or is there an error?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I asked this problem, and one of the users suggests the problem is ill posed.

Here is the statement of the problem, copied exactly from the homework.

Is there really an error in the problem, which makes it unable to be solved?

---

The problem is as follows:

> Suppose $W : [-1,1] \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function. Show that
>
> $$f(t) = \begin{cases}
>  W(t) & \text{if } t \in [-1,0] \\
>  1+W(t) & \text{if } t \in (0,1] \end{cases}$$
>
> is integrable on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with many math terms, what does "integrable" mean?

Comment: "Able to be integrated."

Comment: The problem looks well formed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that, for a function $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$, the quantity

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

exists if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ (save for most finitely many discontinuities on $[a,b]$).

With this in mind, I believe the question is perfectly well-framed and can be solved using the information given.

---

An example of this would be the function on $[0,1]$ given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in [0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1] \\
2 & x = 1/2
\end{cases}$$

which has $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1$. Similarly, for a function on $[0,100]$ defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x \text{ is not an integer} \\
-x^2 & x \text{ is an integer}
\end{cases}$$

has $\int_0^{100} f(x)dx = \int_0^{100} x \, dx$. This becomes clear if you think of things in terms of signed area: how much area would a single point contribute to the whole integral?

Comment: So to solve this particular problem, would there be any particular trick to show this for this problem? should I try to prove that any function with a finite number of discontinuities is integrable? Or can I just state the result?

Comment: That is a matter that would be entirely up to your teacher, I can't speak for what they consider to be allowable. Though if you have already learned this result in class, I would consider it fair game to use. Otherwise, you could attempt to prove it for the case of a single continuity, which would be sufficient for your problem (might make things easier?).

Comment: Also this problem was tied to a problem saying, some continuous functions are the sum or difference of monotonic functions. In the beginning I thought that I was supposed represent this function as a sum of nondecreasing functions, and then use a proof in the first part that all monotone functions are integrable? Though, it took me alot of time trying to represent the function as the sum of nondecreasing functions, and in the end I was never able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: All you know is that $W$ is continuous, so I'm not sure if trying to represent it (or $f$ in turn) as a sum of monotone functions would even be feasible as an approach to be honest.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was thinking after trying to construct the sum for at least an hour.

Comment: Your $f$ is the sum of a continuous function ($W$) and a monotone function. So it's the sum of two integrable functions. Does that help?

Comment: @AndreasBlass you know I think that gave away the answer, the professor was trying to get at. Thanks